# bash script - use and expand variable in cat

Tags: bash, variables, string-interpolation, heredoc

In my bash script I have this:

```
myapphome=/home/username/Documents/myapp

cat << 'EOT' > "$myapphome"/some.properties
dir.root="$myapphome"/app_data
EOT
```

Expected in some.properties:

```
dir.root=/home/username/Documents/myapp/app_data
```

But in actual it is:

```
dir.root="$myapphome"/app_data
```

What I am doing wrong here? I mean I want to expand the $myapphome in my some.properties file.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with `cat`; it's the shell's treatment of the here document that is relevant. The issues involved are the same no matter what process the here document is attached to.

Comment: Yeah right. Now I am getting idea why shell script is called ugly and powerful scripting language. lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want bash to expand variables in a here document, don't quote the terminator:

```sh
cat << EOT > "$myapphome"/some.properties
dir.root=$myapphome/app_data
EOT
```

Also, remove the double quotes from the here document, they won't be removed by the expansion.

See `man bash`:

> If `EOT` is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are  subjected  to  parameter  expansion, command  substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  character sequence `\<newline>` is ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.

Comment: yay.. worked perfectly. As you shared the man bash details I had to escape couple of other $ signs. Its working as desired now for my automated installation script for Alfresco - https://github.com/ajkr195/AlfrescoCommunityInstallation/blob/main/alfresco_automated_installation.sh Thanks a ton for saving my day.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the single quotes from the terminator. The quotes are used when you don't want to expand variables in heredoc:

```sh
cat << EOT > "$myapphome"/some.properties
dir.root=$myapphome/app_data
EOT
```

You might wanna remove the double quotes around your variable as well ;)